# Syntax Error In Python SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

**THE CODE BELOW IS UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS**

I am getting a syntax error when I try to run this. Here is the relevant code:

```
import sqlite3
mydatabase="/Users/noahclark/cities.db"
connection=sqlite3.connect(mydatabase)
cur = connection.cursor()

def getDaysURLS(self):
    day = cur.execute('select state from cities where city = "pointer"')
    day = cur.fetchone()[0]
    print day
    cur.execute('select URL from cities where day = ?', (str(day),))
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
  Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
  File "tkinter.py", line 50, in getDaysURLS
  cur.execute(urlstring)
  OperationalError: near "<": syntax error
```

I can run the -- select state from cities where city is "pointer" -- line in the sqlite command line and it works.

Any ideas or pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that best helped you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use is in sql when checking for null

```
  day = cur.execute('select state from cities where city = "pointer"')
```

Or better yet:

```
  day = cur.execute('select state from cities where city = ?',("pointer",))
```

*EDIT*

```
 urlstring = "select URL from cities where day is" + str(day)
 cur.execute(urlstring)
```

1. Use the ? method I showed previously
2. You need a space after is
3. cur.execute() doesn't return the value like that. I'm not sure what it returns. You need to use a fetch method.

Comment: Winston, why is the second one better?

Comment: @Noah, it doesn't actually make a big difference here. But it takes care of quoting strings for you which is really important if you put user input inside the string.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working and have put the working code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite follows the SQL standard: strings are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.  Also, generally use = to check for string equality.

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes, but the issue remains.

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code and error message?

Comment: @Noah Clark: The error is now on a different line.  You've taken the result from a cur.execute, stringified it, and created a new SQL statement from it.  That doesn't make any sense.  Think through what you are trying to do.

Comment: The code is updated to work. However, help me understand why it doesn't make sense. If I'm pulling an integer don't I need to stringify it to use it in an SQL statement?

Comment: The old code didn't make sense because you weren't getting the integer from the query, you were turning the result set object into a string. Now you've added the lines you need to extract the integer from the result set.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. I didn't know that I wasn't getting what I thought I was getting. I should have used a print statement to double check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use double quotes.  SQLite uses those to escape identifiers such as field and table names.  Use single quotes instead.  Furthermore, you should use `=` instead of `is`:

```
day = cur.execute("select state from cities where city = 'pointer'")
```

---

**UPDATE**:  `cur.execute()` returns the cursor `cur`, not a result from the query.  You need to call `cursor.fetchone()` to get the value:

```
# Execute the query.  If all went well, you can use the cursor to navigate through
# the results.
cur.execute("select state from cities where city = 'pointer'")
# Fetch the next row and extract the first value in the row.
day = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: I changed that! Thanks. The original issue still remains

Comment: The issue does not remain, Python is just pointing to the next bug in your code! :(

Comment: Ferdinard Beyer, You are correct. I figured out the next bug, and am now working on the third bug.

Comment: @Noah: You really have to try to understand what people tell you and try to fix your issues by yourself.  Your last edit made no sense: You are turning the cursor object from `cursor.execute()` into a string, which results into the meaningless `<sqlite3.Cursor object at ...>`!  Just use `print` now and then to see what's going wrong!

Comment: Ferdinand, I got it working with the fetch part. I wasn't trying to not fix the issues my self, but I really wanted to just yell, "Give me a minute to play with this so I can test it and figure it out for my self." But, I also wanted to give SOME update, so people weren't trying to solve a non-issue. It's probably better to give no update at all then?

Comment: No, don't give updates.  Your question was answered and your update just turned it into a completely different question.  Now it is tough to associate your current question text with the answers here.